# Magento rewrite core model resource collection

Tags: magento, url-rewriting

Im trying to rewrite the Mage_Review_Model_Resource_Review_Summary_Collection.
The Module is activated.
The folde structure is the same as in core review.

The problem should be in the xml.

My xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <LM_Review>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </LM_Review>
</modules>

<frontend>
    <routers>
        <review>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <lm_review before="Mage_Review">LM_Review</lm_review>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </review>
    </routers>

    <layout>
        <updates>
            <lm_review>
                <file>lm/review.xml</file>
            </lm_review>
        </updates>
    </layout>

    <translate>
        <modules>
            <LM_Review>
                <files>
                    <default>LM_Review.csv</default>
                </files>
            </LM_Review>
        </modules>
    </translate>
</frontend>

<global>
    <models>
        <review_resource>
            <rewrite>
                <review_summary_collection>LM_Review_Model_Resource_Review_Summary_Collection</review_summary_collection>
            </rewrite>
        </review_resource>
    </models>
</global>
</config>
```

LM_All.xml in etc/modules

```
<LM_Review>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Review />
            </depends>
</LM_Review>
```

The Collection.php in app/code/local/LM/Review/Model/Resource/Review/Summary/Collection.php

```
class LM_Review_Model_Resource_Review_Summary_Collection extends Mage_Review_Model_Resource_Review_Summary_Collection {

   public function addStoreFilter($storeId) {
      die('test');
   }

}
```

Comment: What kind of problem do you face?

Comment: The rewrite isnt working. Im not able to extend the core-class with this xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem. Its required to add the resource-model to the xml and not only rewrite it.

```
<global>
    <models>
        <review>
            <resourceModel>review_resource</resourceModel>
        </review>
        <review_resource>
            <rewrite>
                <review_summary_collection>LM_Review_Model_Resource_Review_Summary_Collection</review_summary_collection>
            </rewrite>
        </review_resource>
    </models>
</global>
```

Comment: I don't see why this supposed to be required. In my particular case I had a typo in etc/config.xml so the xml wasn't valid anymore

Answer (score 6):

Your XML is correct.  With the above XML in place, if you make the factory method call

```
Mage::getResourceModel('review/review_summary_collection')
```

Magento will attempt to instantiate a

```
LM_Review_Model_Resource_Review_Summary_Collection
```

That means

1. Magento can't see your module (no `app/etc/module` file, or file is inactive, or file is pointing to the wrong code pool)
2. You do not have a file at `LM/Review/Model/Resource/Review/Summary/Collection.php` in your code pool
3. The class defined in `Collection.php` is not `LM_Review_Model_Resource_Review_Summary_Collection`
4. The class defined in `Collection.php` does not extend `Mage_Review_Model_Resource_Review_Summary_Collection`
5. Check the spelling and upper/lower case of your class and path names.  This matters to Magento.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
I have checked the spelling and such things. The moule is activeted. There is also an controller in the module which is working. I also rebuild the same folder-strucutre and its extending the core class.
Its not my 1st model-rewrite but my 1st resource-model-rewrite and I dont see whats wrong with it. I have also Firegento installed which also says that something is wrong with the rewrite but no details.

Comment: @exe `echo get_class(Mage::getResourceModel('review/review_summary_collection'));` who knows it has been overridden by other modules

Comment: Already testet -> Mage_Review_Model_Resource_Review_Summary_Collection  its not overridden my somethign else. Also updated the 1st post with more infos

Comment: @exe -- here's a module with a working rewrite.  Diff vs. yours.  http://alanstorm.com/2013/projects/LM_Review.tar.gz

Comment: Ya thanks but I have found the problem and posted it some hours before your Answer and I have checked it and I think it woulnd work for me. But thanks alot